# How to create a template class that can handle std::set with different type parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates, set

I need to write a template in C++ that implements an abstract version of a set. I can't find a solution (or worse, don't really understand what to do) about a compile error.

This is a simplified version of the main program I need to compile and run -- that is, I MUST NOT change anything in this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include "testset.h"

using namespace std;

struct string_size_less
{

  bool operator()( const std::string& a,
                   const std::string& b )
  {
    return a.size() < b.size();
  }

};

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> msgs;
    msgs.insert("One");
    msgs.insert("Two");
    msgs.insert("Three");

    set_ops<std::string> ops(msgs);
    ops.list();

    std::set<std::string, string_size_less> x;
    x.insert("Hello");
    x.insert("Ciao");

    std::set<std::string, std::greater<std::string> > a;
    a.insert(":-o");

    set_ops<std::string> m(x);
    m.list();

    return 0;
}
```

I need to write the 'set_ops' class (in testset.h). I stripped all the non-relevant parts (that otherwise work):

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class set_ops
{
    private:
        std::set<T> elements;

    public:
        set_ops(std::set<T> initialSet)
        {
            elements = initialSet;
        }

        void list() const;
};

template <class T> void set_ops<T>::list() const
{
    for (typename set<T>::iterator i = elements.begin(); i != elements.end(); ++i) {
        cout << "\t" << *i << endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error:

```
In function 'int main()':
error: no matching function for call to 'set_ops<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::set_ops(std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, string_size_less>&)'
note: candidate: set_ops<T>::set_ops(std::set<T>) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]|
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, string_size_less>' to 'std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >'
```

I have tried many things and tried to find a good example, etc., but so far found none. I know for example (and tried it) that if I add another template parameter like this:

```
template <class T, class U = std::less<T> > class set_ops
{
    private:
        std::set<T, U> elements;

    public:
        set_ops(std::set<T, U> initialSet)
        {
            elements = initialSet;
        }

        void list() const;
};

template <class T, class U> void set_ops<T, U>::list() const
{
    for (typename set<T, U>::iterator i = elements.begin(); i != elements.end(); ++i) {
        cout << "\t" << *i << endl;
    }
}
```

then if I explicitly write:

```
set_ops<std::string, string_size_less> m(x);
```

it compiles and runs without error. But, again, I MUST NOT change anything in main(), so that's not an option.

If I keep the line from the original main(), I get the same compile error even with the changes in testset.h.

I'd really like to understand the problem (and hopefully the solution) here, if anyone could help. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK this can't be done without changing `main`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed it can by abusing polymorphism.

Comment: Is the output specified? else you can copy content and change order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved through polymorphism and a template constructor.

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class set_ops
{
private:
    // Interface type.
    class set_ops_iface
    {
    public:
        virtual ~set_ops_iface();

        virtual void list() const = 0;
    };

    // Concrete implementation for a U.
    template <typename U>
    class set_ops_impl : public set_ops_iface
    {
    private:
        U value;

    public:
        explicit set_ops_impl(U);

        virtual void list() const override;
    };

private:
    // Smart pointer to interface type.
    std::unique_ptr<set_ops_iface> impl;

public:
    // Template constructor that can take any kind of container (not just sets)
    template <typename U>
    set_ops(U);

    void list() const;
};

// Template constructor creates a set_ops_impl<U> owned by the interface smart pointer.
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
set_ops<T>::set_ops(U initial) :
    impl{std::make_unique<set_ops_impl<U>>(std::move(initial))} { }

template <typename T>
set_ops<T>::set_ops_iface::~set_ops_iface() { }

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
set_ops<T>::set_ops_impl<U>::set_ops_impl(U initial) :
    value{std::move(initial)} { }

// real list() implementation is in set_ops_impl<U>
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void set_ops<T>::set_ops_impl<U>::list() const {
    for (auto const & i : value) {
        std::cout << '\t' << i << '\n';
    }
}

// set_ops::list proxies to the polymorphic implementation.
template <typename T>
void set_ops<T>::list() const {
    impl->list();
}
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e07cd1f1875cb83))

Note that, curiously, we don't even use the `T` template argument.  `set_ops` wouldn't even need to be a template type if `main()` didn't require that it is.

To add another member function, you have to:

1. Add the implementation to the `set_ops::set_ops_impl` template.
2. Add a proxy member to `set_ops`.

Comment: Doesn't this then require you to have `N` `std::function` members, one for each function that needs to be implemented?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. It's a bit of a hack but satisfies the constraints of the question. If more members are added then it would be better to factor the captured `initial` out as a `set_ops` member which can be done in a type-safe way with proper destruction of the captured object, it would just take a bit of work to get exactly right. .... Another approach would be to have each lambda capture an `std::shared_ptr<U>` by value, though that would not be as efficient.

Comment: If you can you might want to provide that solution since the OP's example has been paired down to just the minimal essentials.  It looks as though `set_ops` needs to provide all of the set interface.

Comment: @NathanOliver Doing so now.

Comment: @NathanOliver Done

Comment: @cdhowie Thank you very much! I just compiled and ran the code. Finally I have some example to look at and digest, to try to understand this better. :)

Comment: @AlizaWenders If you have a lot of members on this type, a more straightforward implementation would have a private abstract class that is inherited by a template class, and the `set_ops` template constructor would just heap-allocate an instance of that template class, storing the result on a local member. In fact, that's probably a much better way to do it than I did it here.  `std::function` is much simpler when you have one method, but gets more complex the more members you have.

Comment: @cdhowie Hm, I'll look into that too. I forgot to say that I needed to do all this in C++98/99 standard :D, but your solution gave me the push in the right direction and just now I compiled and ran a version (based on your answer) with list() and another function, union(), that can also take a slightly differently typed parameter, and it's working with C++98. I guess what I really didn't understand is how to use T and U correctly to enable the code to handle different (sub)types. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @AlizaWenders I rewrote it using a polymorphic interface/implementation instead of storing a bunch of functions. IMO this is cleaner, easier to understand, and easier to extend. It's also more portable to pre-C++11. You just have to remove `std::move` and replace `std::unique_ptr` with either `std::auto_ptr` (eww) or a raw pointer and manage its lifetime yourself, appropriately restricting copying of `set_ops`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer works because `std::function` uses a technique called "type erasure". If you don't want to keep multiple `std::functions`, you can instead implement type erasure yourself.

```
template<typename T>
struct set_ops_erased {
    virtual ~set_ops_erased() = default;
    virtual void list() = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename Comp>
struct set_ops_impl : set_ops_erased<T> {
    std::set<T, Comp> s;
    set_ops_impl(std::set<T, Comp> s) : s(std::move(s)) { }
    void list() override {
        for(auto &x : s) std::cout << "\t" << x << "\n"; // endl is normally not necessary
    }
};

template<typename T>
class set_ops {
     std::unique_ptr<set_ops_erased<T>> ops;
public:
     template<typename Comp>
     set_ops(std::set<T, Comp> s)
     : ops(std::make_unique<set_ops_impl<T, Comp>>(std::move(s)))
     { }

     void list() { ops->list(); }
};
```

In this case, there's no need to worry about writing all the copy/move constructors/assignments and destructors. They just do the right thing. Because there is just one allocation of `set_ops_impl`, there's no need to think about using a "guarding" `std::unique_ptr` to clean up the container while the `set_ops` is being constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing main file, but forgetting initial order of given set (as you don't specify expected output), you might do:

```
template <class T> class set_ops
{
private:
    std::set<T> elements;

public:
    template <typename Container>
    set_ops(Container& c) : elements(c.begin(), c.end()) {}

    void list() const {
        for (const auto& e : elements) {
            std::cout << "\t" << e << std::endl;
        }  
    }
};
```